# Navigating to a single page from a Drawer in React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have three bottom tabs, each with access to the same Drawer navigation. In the Drawer nav I am using drawerContent and drawerItems to have custom content links to pages outside of the tab (ie. I don't want the tabs showing on these pages). However, I can't seem to pass in the navigation prop - I receive 'navigation.navigate is not a function'.

EDIT: Basically I would like to link to pages outside of the tabs (not showing the tabs) from the drawer, with a back button etc.. I think I need a createStackNavigator in there somewhere but I can't work out how to incorporate it.

Here's the code:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function TabOne({ navigation }) {
    return (
         <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} navigation={navigation} />}>
             <Drawer.Screen name="Tab One" component={TabOneScreen} />
         </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

function TabTwo({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} navigation={navigation} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Tab Two" component={TabTwoScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

function TabThree({ navigation }) {
    return (
        <Drawer.Navigator drawerContent={props => <CustomDrawerContent {...props} navigation={navigation} />}>
            <Drawer.Screen name="Tab Three" component={TabThreeScreen} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
    );
}

function CustomDrawerContent(props, navigation) {
    return (
        <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
            <DrawerItemList {...props} />

            // THIS LINE HERE
            <DrawerItem label="Settings" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Settings')} />

            <DrawerItem label="Logout" onPress={() => LogOut()} />
        </DrawerContentScrollView>
    )
}

function TabOneScreen() {
    return (
        <>
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Tab One Screen</Text>
        </View>
        </>
    );
 }

 function TabTwoScreen() {
     return (
         <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
            <Text>Tab Two Screen</Text>
         </View>
     );
 }

 function TabThreeScreen() {
     return (
         <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
             <Text>Tab Three Screen</Text>
         </View>
     );
 }

 export default function App() {
     return (
         <NavigationContainer>
             <Tab.Navigator>
                 <Tab.Screen name="Tab One" component={TabOne} />
                 <Tab.Screen name="Tab Two" component={TabTwo} />
                 <Tab.Screen name="Tab Three" component={TabThree} />
             </Tab.Navigator>
         </NavigationContainer>
     );
 }
```

Also, I'm not sure how to 'include' the linked Settings page/component in the DrawerItem as it's not included in any navigation stack.

What would be the correct way to do this?

Cheers, Matt

Answer (score 0):

Crete a parent navigator with `createStackNavigator` and then include your tab navigator and the non-tabbed screens as child components of that parent navigator